# sort data and display items in Angular Tables

Tags: angular, angular-material

First I want to display the data on the angular table, that only works if I select on the footer "items per page".

If I don't do that, the table shows empty rows.

[image: click on the footer 'items per page', contents will display]

Here is the html file:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> key </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
    </ng-container>



    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
    </ng-container>



    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 10, 10]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

in .ts
I already type:

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'key', 'value'];

  ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = new Array<PeriodicElement>();

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit(): void { 

 ..... <deleted code>...
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

}

2. It seems the sort function didn't work, I did the same as in the documentation

   > ```
   > ngAfterViewInit() {
   >     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   >     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   >   }
   > ```

Both libraries are imported:

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
```

Comment: ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = new Array<PeriodicElement>(); - your datasource is empty. Where do you fill datasource?

Comment: I fill the data in the ngOnit. The data comes from service component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it seems like you didn't tell `mat-paginator` what should be the `pageSize` try the following:

```html
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 10, 10]" [pageSize]=10 showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

if that works, try with variable instead of constant value

2. about sorting - I think you need to use `mat-sort-header` inside `mat-header-cell` to make it work
3. make sure you have these modules to `app.module.ts` file:

```js
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

and you initialize `sort` and `paginator` only in this one method like:

```js
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Here's stackblitz example with basic setup to make paginator and sort work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uatatb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks, I already declared this, but the error is still the same.

Comment: You can also try to initialize the `this.dataSource.sort` and `.paginator` in `ngOnInit` method, not after view init and see what happens

Comment: wait, did you `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator` twice?

Comment: yes, one in ngOnInit() and once in ngAfterviewInit()

Comment: try to cut ngAfterviewInit contents into ngOnInit ; I also updated my answer - check `mat-sort-header`

Comment: ok thanks for updating. Let me check with mat-sort-header